# Why is L2 regularization not added back into original loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, computer-vision

I'm aware that when using a kernal regularizer, particularly, l2 loss, I should bee add it back into the loss function and this is what is being done in other posts. However, in Keras, they are not following this process. Why is this so?

For instance, consider [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/cifar-10/discussion/40237) and [this](https://www.kaggle.com/dm2017/cnn-kernel-regularizer-and-dropout-added) notebook. They are using l2 loss as a kernal regularizer in some layers but not adding back into the original loss. Is this because of the particular loss, or is this a behavior followed in just Keras or am I completely misunderstanding everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keras hides a lot of complexity (and this is not always a good thing).

You're using the `Model` abstraction: this model contains inside all the required information about the architecture and the training procedure.

When you invoke the method `compile` or `train` or `train_on_batch` you specify the loss function but under the hood what happens is:

- Instantiate the loss function specified (e.g. categorical cross entropy)
- Fetch from the model the regularizations applied and add all of them to the loss term previously instantiated

You can see the operations that are going to be added to the loss term accessing to the property `.losses` of the model instance (that's a list of tensorflow operations, usually all multilication operations, since the regularizations are in the for `regularization_strenght * norm_p(variable)`.

Answer (score 1):

The L2 regularization (or any weight regularization) in Keras is still added to the loss function in the same way as you would expect. It just happens behind the scene, so the user doesn't need to worry about it.

The notebooks you linked are the right way to use weight regularization in Keras.